# JavaScript: Remove duplicates from array of objects

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have an array of data which looks like this.

```
data = [ 
  { "name": "Apple", "type": "Fruit"}, 
  { "name": "Cabbage", "type": "Vegetable"} , 
  { "name": "Orange", "type": "Fruit"} 
]
```

I want to filter out the element which its `type` already existed.
And I want to keep the first element.

*E.g. keep Apple instead of Orange*

```
data = [ 
  { "name": "Apple", "type": "Fruit"},
  { "name": "Cabbage", "type": "Vegetable"}
]
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get all unique values in a JavaScript array (remove duplicates)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1960473/get-all-unique-values-in-a-javascript-array-remove-duplicates)

Comment: What have you attempted till now? A loop logic will help you to achieve this. Where are you stuck with?

Comment: @derpirscher the question might look the same but it's actually not. That solution does not answer my question because the array I have is an object array. Thanks for you help tho.

Comment: @Nitheesh I am trying using .filter instead of loop but it's not working for me.

Comment: @Jonnie Please accept the relavent answer and close this thread.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [`Array#filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter), you can iterate over the array while updating a [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) to keep track of types added:

```js
const data = [ { "name": "Apple", "type": "Fruit"}, { "name": "Cabbage", "type": "Vegetable"}, { "name": "Orange", "type": "Fruit"} ];

const typeSet = new Set();
const res = data.filter(({ type }) => {
  if(typeSet.has(type)) return false;
  typeSet.add(type);
  return true;
});

console.log(res);
```

Comment: Thank you bro. This is exactly what I am looking for

Answer (score 1):

**1)** You can filter the result if `type` already not present in `dict` using [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) as:

```
data.filter((o) => (dict.has(o.type) ? false : dict.add(o.type, true)))
```

```js
const data = [
  { name: "Apple", type: "Fruit" },
  { name: "Cabbage", type: "Vegetable" },
  { name: "Orange", type: "Fruit" },
];

const dict = new Set();
const result = data.filter((o) => (dict.has(o.type) ? false : dict.add(o.type, true)));
console.log(result)
```

**2)** You can also use [`for..of`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) and [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) as:

```js
const data = [
  { name: "Apple", type: "Fruit" },
  { name: "Cabbage", type: "Vegetable" },
  { name: "Orange", type: "Fruit" },
];

const dict = new Set(), result = [];

for (let o of data) {
  if (!dict.has(o.type)) {
    result.push(o);
    dict.add(o.type);
  }
}

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Thank you for help. Really appreciate that you also provide another way of doing this.